# Post method invocation interception with Cglib

Tags: java, guice, interceptor, cglib

I was wondering if it is possible to intercept a method after the invocation of the target method?
For example as you can see below:

```
@CleanUp
public void doSomething{
...
}
```

I want to be able to intercept the method after the method invocation.
In above sample, I will do common clean up after the invocation of method.

Comment: Yes, you can use aspect oriented programming. Maybe start [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the standard CGLIB Enhancer you can choose whether you want to execute code before or after the method being proxied is invoked.  For instance:

```
MyClass proxy = (List<String>)Enhancer.create(MyClass.class, new MyInvocationHandler());
proxy.aMethodToInvoke();
.
.
.
class MyInvocationHandler implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before we invoke the method");
        Object retObj = proxy.invoke(obj, args);
        System.out.println("After we invoke the method");
        return retObj;
    }
}
```

So anything after the `proxy.invoke` call will be code which executes after the method being proxy has been called and has returned.